# What is the "login session" of a process?

Tags: login, ps, session

In [the manpage of ps](http://man.he.net/man1/ps)

> `lsession    SESSION`   displays login session identifier of a process.

What does the "login session" of a process mean?

`ps` has other fields `cgname` and `cgroup` for the cgroup of a process. So the login session of a process can't refer to the cgroup of the process.

Thanks.

```
$ ps  -o lsession,pid,cmd
SESSION       PID CMD
c2          22135 bash
c2          27852 ps -o lsession,pid,cmd
```

Comment: Based on your previous questions, can we assume this is a Linux-based question? You quoted a 7 year old man page of procps, so it's good to clarify.  Current procps-ng contains a comment "displays the login session identifier of a process, if systemd support has been included"

Comment: My system shows a very suspicious correlation between the lsession and the cgname/cgroup output (session-`lsession`.scope)

Comment: @JeffSchaller But what if it's not compiled with systemd support? The manpage seems to be very unclear. According to OP, it is very likely showing the logind session name, but that definilty needs compile-time option and running systemd-logind support.

Comment: Agreed, @炸鱼薯条德里克, which is why I asked Tim to clarify the Operating System environment in question here.